# Possible exception to the subject-verb agreement rule

Tags: verb-agreement

> Slight ***movements*** in the resonant peak ***are*** attributed to the changes in the refractive index.

I know that normally, ***are*** is correct since ***movements*** is in plural, but I wonder if I can use ***is*** instead? (with ***movements***) The reason I ask is that I kind of prefer saying ***is***, since I want to refer to the (event of) movements **happening**, which would be singular, but I don't know if this is grammatically acceptable, or if this is done in practice as an option.

Comment: I personally would find "*movements ... is*" very awkward. I don't recommend it.

Comment: What an unusual (and, if I may say so, self-inflicted) dilemma. Why don't you therefore start by saying *The event of ....is...*?

Comment: No, but instead of "movements", you can refer to "variation", which will give you the singular you long for.

Comment: **I want to refer to the (event of) movements happening, which would be singular**. The participle "happening" is not specifically singular or plural, so (a) your problem is not clear, and (b) you can resolve it with a simple recast. But whatever you decide, you cannot break the subject / verb agreement rule, and be considered correct.

Comment: I think this is an [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)-level question. Singular ***movement*** is quite acceptable even if it refers to multiple separate "movements".

Comment: Wouldn't the singular imply a uniform shift over time, say a translation of the peak higher or lower, while the @GregLee solution would imply a random distribution of peak values?  Or is it just me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make *movements* singular by force of preference, but you could substitute a singular noun that means the same thing. Such as

> Slight variation/oscillation/deflection in the resonant peak is attributed to the changes in the refractive index.

or whatever is appropriate to describe the movements.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible; at least not the way it's written.

You could, however, recast it something like: "The detection of slight movements in the resonant peak is attributed to the changes in the refractive index".

Comment: I don't want to get into the philosophy of science here, but might this not imply that the changes in the RI affect the detection and not the actual movements?  Or is it just me?